# Using simple HTML template to create HTML formatting rules

Tags: c#, html, regex, formatting, template

One of my tools that renders HTML needs some rules about document formatting. The renderer can format the output so that it is indented and contains appropriate line-breaks. In the first version I used a hardcoded dictionary that looks like this:

> ```
> public class HtmlFormatting : MarkupFormatting
> {
>     public const int DefaultIndentWidth = 4;
>
>     public HtmlFormatting() : this(DefaultIndentWidth)
>     {
>         this["body"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine;
>         this["br"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.IsVoid;
>         //this["span"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.None;
>         this["p"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["pre"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h1"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h2"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h3"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h4"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h5"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["h6"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["ul"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["ol"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["li"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["table"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine;
>         this["caption"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["thead"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["tbody"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["tfoot"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["tr"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine;
>         this["th"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>         this["td"] = MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine;
>     }
>
>     public HtmlFormatting(int indentWidth)
>     {
>         IndentWidth = indentWidth;
>     }
> }
> ```

As with everything hardcoded it's not very maintenance friendly and doesn't allow me to change or add new formattings without recompiling the application.

---

In order to fix this I thought why not derive the formatting from a real HTML? This way I already can see the output so everything starts with a template. This is how I expect the generated HTML to look like:

```
var template = @"
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2></h2>
        <p><br><span></span></p>
        <div>   </div>
        <hr>
        <ol>
        </ol>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <table>
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>          
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>  
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>";
```

With a few patterns, groupings and conditions I then determine the formatting for each element. Because I'm not interested in parsing the HTML but only finding the number of tags, their rows and columns I used regex. A template would never be anything else then the example above. For the sake of this question let's assume the HTML is always valid.

What the expression does is to basically split the template on line breaks and calculates the row and column numbers for each tag. Then based on that I can tell

- whether an element is a void element if it occurs only once in the template
- whether its opening tag should be placed on a new line if it doesn't have any predecessors (based on the column number)
- whether its closing tag should be placed on a new line if both its tags have different row numbers (or there are simply two different row numbers)

```
static class MarkupFormattingTemplate
{
    public static IDictionary<string, MarkupFormattingOptions> Parse(string template)
    {
        var tags =
            template
                .ToLines()
                .Parse()
                .ToList();

        var openingTagOptions = tags.DetermineOpeningTagOptions();
        var closingTagOptions = tags.DetermineClosingTagOptions();

        return Merge(openingTagOptions, closingTagOptions);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> ToLines(this string template)
    {
        return
            Regex
                .Split(template, @"(\r\n|\r|\n)")
                // Remove empty lines.
                .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tag> Parse(this IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        return
            lines
                .Select((line, lineNumber) =>
                    ParseLine(line)
                    // Select tag properties for grouping.
                    .Select(m => new Tag
                    {
                        Name = m.Groups["name"].Value,
                        Line = lineNumber,
                        Column = m.Groups["name"].Index
                    }))
                .SelectMany(x => x);

        IEnumerable<Match> ParseLine(string line)
        {
            return
                Regex
                    // Find tag names.
                    .Matches(line, @"</?(?<name>[a-z0-9]+)>", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
                    .Cast<Match>();
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>> DetermineClosingTagOptions(this IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
    {
        // Group elements by name to first find out where to place the closing tag.
        foreach (var g in tags.GroupBy(t => t.Name))
        {
            var closingTagOptions =
                // If any tag has more the one row then the closing tag should be placed on a new line.
                (g.Select(i => i.Line).Distinct().Count() > 1 ? MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine : MarkupFormattingOptions.None) |
                // If any tag occurs only once then it's void.
                (g.Count() == 1 ? MarkupFormattingOptions.IsVoid : MarkupFormattingOptions.None);

            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>(g.Key, closingTagOptions);
        };
    }

    private static  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>> DetermineOpeningTagOptions(this IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
    {
        foreach (var tagName in tags.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var openingTagOptions =
                 tags
                    .GroupBy(t => t.Line)
                    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Name == tagName))
                    .First()
                    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                    .First(x => x.item.Name == tagName).index == 0
                        ? MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
                        : MarkupFormattingOptions.None;

            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>(tagName, openingTagOptions);
        }
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, MarkupFormattingOptions> Merge(
         IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>> options1, 
         IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>> options2)
    {
        var result = options1.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (var item in options2)
        {
            result[item.Key] |= item.Value;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private class Tag
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public int Column { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Formatting options are defined by an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum MarkupFormattingOptions
{
    None = 0,
    PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine = 1,
    PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine = 2,
    PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine =
        PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine |
        PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine,
    IsVoid = 4,
    CloseEmptyTag = 8
}
```

---

To visualize the steps here are some intermediate results:

**Step one**: split on new lines so this is actually the same as the template:

```
<body> 
    <h1></h1> 
    <h2></h2> 
    <p><br><span></span></p> 
  <div>  </div> 
    <hr> 
    <ol> 
    </ol> 
    <ul> 
        <li></li> 
    </ul> 
    <table> 
        <thead> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>           
            <tr> 
          <th></th> 
                <td></td> 
            </tr>   
        </tbody> 
        <tfoot> 
        </tfoot> 
    </table> 
</body>
```

**Step two**: tag names and their row and column numbers:

```
name    row column
body    0   3
h1      1   7
h1      1   12
h2      2   7
h2      2   12
p       3   7
br      3   10
span    3   14
span    3   21
p       3   28
div     4   4
div     4   11
hr      5   7
ol      6   7
ol      7   8
ul      8   7
li      9   11
li      9   16
ul      10  8
table   11  7
thead   12  11
thead   13  12
tbody   14  11
tr      15  15
th      16  10
th      16  15
td      17  19
td      17  24
tr      18  16
tbody   19  12
tfoot   20  11
tfoot   21  12
table   22  8
body    23  4
```

**Step three**: finding closing tag options:

```
body    PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
h1      None
h2      None
p       None
br      IsVoid
span    None
div     None
hr      IsVoid
ol      PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
ul      PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
li      None
table   PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
thead   PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
tbody   PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
tr      PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
th      None
td      None
tfoot   PlaceClosingTagOnNewLine
```

**Step four**: finding opening tag options and merging it with the previous step so at the same time this is the final step:

```
body    PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
h1      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
h2      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
p       PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
br      IsVoid
span    None
div     PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
hr      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine, IsVoid
ol      PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
ul      PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
li      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
table   PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
thead   PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
tbody   PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
tr      PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
th      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
td      PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
tfoot   PlaceBothTagsOnNewLine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I hate deciphering Regex expressions. So I would not use it unless necessary. You should be able to split string in to lines using `String.Split` method just fine with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. Also `string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim())` is basically `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)`, is it not?

`Determine*` methods IMHO will look better if you add a couple of local variables:

```
private static  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>> DetermineOpeningTagOptions(this IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
{
    var lines = tags.GroupBy(t => t.Line).ToArray();
    var tagNames = tags.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach (var tagName in tagNames)
    {
        var line = lines.First(l => l.Any(t => t.Name == tagName));

       //you are only interested in first item
        var formatting = line.First().Name == tagName 
                    ? MarkupFormattingOptions.PlaceOpeningTagOnNewLine
                    : MarkupFormattingOptions.None;

        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, MarkupFormattingOptions>(tagName, formatting);
    }
}
```